# Create folder with Todays Date, create subfolder and copy all files into it - Bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell

```
mkdir -p /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/STYLING\ /backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1

cp -r "/Volumes/styleshoot/TJXE-HHPS-SS01/ss1" "/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/STYLING\ /backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1"

cp -r "/Volumes/styleshoot/TJXE-HHPS-SS01/ph back s " "/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/STYLING\ /backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)/SS1"
```

I am able to create a folder with todays date and "SS1" subfolder inside.

Although, It won't let me `cp -r` into this newly created folder? It states "no such file or directory". Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Asside from what PesaThe correctly said, your approach would fail if the script is executed so close to midnight that one of the `cp` commands would be executed on the following day, i.e. the day after the `mkdir` has been performed. For this reason, and of course also for maintanability, you should first store the directory name in a variable and use this variable for `mkdir` and `cp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought! I ended up using `find` command to search for any files within the Folder and its all sub-folders. `mkdir -p`- meaning mkdir will create a directory and any parents that don't already exist. `$(date +%Y%m%d)/` to create a folder with **Todays Date**. Then you can simply add `/newfolder/nefolder1`to create any subdirectories within it.

```
#Make Directory for Backups
mkdir -p /path/$(date +%Y%m%d)/NewFolder

#Copy Files into Backup folder
find /path/a/ -type f -exec cp {} /path/$(date +%Y%m%d)/NewFolder;

#Remove Original files
find /path/a/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -delete
```

If needed you can also use `mv` to move files:

```
#Move Files into Backup folder
find /path/a/ -type f -exec mv {} /path/$(date +%Y%m%d)/NewFolder;
```